# Indexing CJK and strip HTML tags

Tags: solr, ezpublish

I am using eZ Find, a front end of eZ Publish to solr, to index some fields containing japanese text and html tags.

I modified the text analyzer as below in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

if for example my custom field is containing:

```
<h1>ほげほげ<h1>
<p>すもももももももものうち</p>
```

and I search for `すもも` in the solr admin, html tags are in the result:

```
<str name="attr_free_1_t"><h1>ほげほげ<h1><p>すもももももももものうち</p></str>
```

How could I prevent the HTML tags from getting indexed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Using [solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory), you could only stop the HTML tags from being **"Indexed"** but not  from being **"Stored"**.

In other words, you will get results for `"すもももももももものうち"` (Of course with HTML tags), but not for `"<p>すもももももももものうち</p>"`.

**Note:** The asumption is that you dont strip off html tags during searching.

If you don't want these HTML tags to be indexed, you can use [solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory).

Your configuration may look like,

```
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                    pattern="Your regular expression to match HTML tags" 
                    replacement=""/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, stored string and indexed string are different. As I just care about the indexed string my current settings will be fine, but nice trick with the regular expression.